# jQuery Autocomplete on select of a menu item, how to override the focus back into the input?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm trying to extend the jQuery autocomplete plugin with something as simple as:

Superbox = {

```
//Options to be used as defaults
options:{
    triggerStart:"@",
    triggerEnd:"",
    position: { my : "left bottom", at: "left top" }
},

_init: function() {
      // stuff
},

_create:function() {
    this.triggered = false;

    this.element.autocomplete($.extend({

        open: function(event, ui) {
 .....

$.widget("ui.autocompleteTrigger", Superbox);
```

Right now I can't figure out how to override the situation where you see the autosuggest menu, you select an item and the textarea gets focus. How can I override that focus? I can't find where that binding is in the pluin? After an autosuggest item selection, I want to focus on a different element.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `select` callback function for this. Something like this should work:

```
select: function(){ $('input#id').blur(); }
```